# using express angularJs and mongoDB but ngResource in angular not loading

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, angularjs, express

Here Is my MongoDB backend code

```
 var mongo = require("mongodb");
 var DbHost = "127.0.0.1";
 var DbPort = mongo.Connection.DEFAULT_PORT;


  module.exports.list = list;

  var db = new mongo.Db("ferrari-db",new mongo.Server(DbHost,DbPort,{}),{safe:true});
  var collectionName  = "carsList";


  function list(req,res,callback){

     db.open(function(error){
        db.collection(collectionName,function(error,collection){
           console.log("have the collection");
           collection.find().toArray(function(error,data){
               if (error) callback(false);
                else{
                   callback(true);
                   console.log(data);
                   res.json(data);

                  }
             });

          });
      });
   }
```

Here is my Node.js express code

```
   var express = require('express');
   var http = require('http');
   var path = require('path');
   var cars = require('./server/api/cars.js')

   var app = express();

   var client_dir =  path.join(__dirname, '/client')
   // all environments
   app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
   app.use(express.favicon());
   app.use(express.logger('dev'));
   app.use(express.bodyParser());
   app.use(app.router);
   app.use(express.static(client_dir));


   // development only
   if ('development' == app.get('env')) {
        app.use(express.errorHandler());
    }

   app.get('/', function(req,res){
       res.sendfile(path.join(client_dir,'index.html'))

    });

    app.get('/api/cars',cars.list);

    http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), function(){
         console.log('Express server listening on port ' + app.get('port'));
    });
```

Here is my angularJs app.js code

```
var CarApp = angular.module('CarApp',['ngResource'])

CarApp.config(function($routeProvider){
    $routeProvider
        .when('/',{controller:ListCtrl,templateUrl:'partials/list.html'})
         .otherwise({redirectTo:'/'})

 }) ;

 CarApp.factory('Cars',function($resource){
      return $resource('/api/cars/:id',{id:'@id'},{update:{method:'PUT'}})
 });

 function ListCtrl ($scope,Cars){

     $scope.cars = Cars.query();

 }
```

Here is index.html file

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Ferrari</title>


 <link type="text/css" rel= "stylesheet" href="vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css"/>
 <script src="vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
 <script src="vendor/angular.min.js"></script>
 <script src="vendor/angular-resource.min.js"></script>
 <script src="js/app.js"></script>

 <body>
 <h1>Hello</h1>

      <div ng-app="CarApp" class="container">
           <div ng-view>
            </div>
      </div>
  </body>

  </html>
```

here is my list.html file

```
 <table class= "table table-bordered table-hover">
  <thead>
      <th>Type</th>
      <th>Mileage</th>
      <th>Year</th>
      <th>Price</th>
  </thead>

<tr ng-repeat="car in cars">
    <td>{{ car.title }}</td>
    <td>{{ car.mileage }}</td>
    <td>{{ car.year }}</td>
    <td>{{ car.price }}</td>
</tr>

</table>
```

The list.html template is loading . I get the error **Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)** ? Also i get the error **Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.**  I can log out the data in console in list method.  Any help would be highly appreciable?

Comment: anytime you hit a 500 error on a web service you need to grab that POST or GET and run it at the command line with cURL. Isolation is always the first step in troubleshooting.

Comment: i use cURl http://127.0.0.1:3000 i get the index.html file but when i do cURl http://127.0.0.1:3000/api/cars i get the same error

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is inside the `cars.list` function.

The structure for an Express route is the following `function myRoute(req, res, next) {...}`.
The `next` function (or `callback` as you put it) is only useful if you have another function after in the middleware.
Maybe the `errorHandler` middleware is called afterwards (`app.get('/api/cars', cars.list);`), I'm not sure about that.

The problem might be that you call `callback(true)` which launches the next middleware (and sends a response, with **headers**, etc.), and then tries to send another response with `res.json(...)`.
You need to drop `callback(true)`.

So I think you should rewrite your function like that:

```
function list(req, res, next) {

  db.open(function (error) {
    db.collection(collectionName, function (error, collection) {
      console.log('Have the collection');
      collection.find().toArray(function(error,data){
        if (error) {
          // Hopefully we pass the error to the error handler
          return next(error);
        } else {
          // If everything goes fine we send the data.
          console.log(data);
          return res.json(data);
        }
      });
    });
  });
}
```